# Why can't I install Windows 8 in Virtualbox on 12.04?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, 32-bit, windows-8

> **Note:** This appears to be a problem with Windows 8, no matter what host OS Virtualbox is running on.

I recently tried to install Windows 8 RP 32-bit in Virtualbox using Ubuntu 12.04 as the host. I have tried multiple settings for memory, hard drive size, etc. Every single time it has come up with this error

```
Your PC needs to restart.
Please hold down the power button
Error code: 0x0000005D
Parameters: 0x0306170A, 0x756E6547, 0x49656E69, 0x6C65746E
```

I really like windows 8 and I would like to know how to fix this some time soon.

Comment: This is what happens http://dietrichschroff.blogspot.de/2012/06/virtualbox-windows-8-and-error.html

Comment: Check your BIOS settings, specially, the CPU related.

Comment: This should be re-opened IMO because (a) the answer involves some settings on Virtualbox, which is running on Ubuntu 12.04 and (b) this seems likely to recur as more folks try Windows 8

Comment: @izx - whatever we do we need to be consistent.  N.B. as per this Meta - this would fall into the off-topic side of installing OS's in virtualbox: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2425/wheres-the-off-topic-line

Comment: @fossfreedom: thanks--especially for that meta Q--in retrospect it does seem that this is off-topic, since Uri's blog link indicates this is probably a platform-independent issue with Windows 8, rather than Virtualbox per se.

Answer (score 4):

The [solution appears to be](http://dietrichschroff.blogspot.com/2012/06/virtualbox-windows-8-and-error.html?showComment=1340116567562#c2050314346560474898):

1. In **BIOS**:

   - Enable VT-x
   - Enable VT-d
2. In **Virtualbox** with Win8 VM off:

   - Enable PAE/NX
   - Enable VT-x
   - Enabled Nested Paging

as well make sure you are using IDE instead of SATA....... T[m}